# Compile notebook in RStudio when Hebrew characters are in the path? (currently, it fails)

Tags: r, encoding, rstudio, knitr, hebrew

When pressing the compile notebook button in RStudio, I get the following error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Dropbox/Teaching/TAU/2016 - b/׳׳‘׳•׳ ׳׳¡׳˜׳˜׳™׳¡׳˜׳™׳§׳” - ׳׳¡׳˜׳˜׳™׳¡׳˜׳™׳§׳׳™׳/׳×׳™׳¨׳’׳•׳׳™׳/stat_intro_2016/intro_stat.R': No such file or directory
```

This is my actual path:

```
getwd()
[1] "C:/Dropbox/Teaching/TAU/2016 - b/מבוא לסטטיסטיקה - לסטטיסטיקאים/תירגולים/stat_intro_2016"
```

Here is my session info (I tried using:  Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Hebrew")  and it didn't help)

```
> sessionInfo()
R Under development (unstable) (2016-02-08 r70124)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Hebrew_Israel.1255  LC_CTYPE=Hebrew_Israel.1255   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Hebrew_Israel.1255 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Hebrew_Israel.1255    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] htmltools_0.3   tools_3.3.0     rmarkdown_0.9.2 digest_0.6.9   
>
```

Any suggestion where this parameter can be set?

Thanks.

Comment: If I name my file with localized characters (not in latin1 charset), I get the same error. My locale (in Windows) somehow doesn't support UTF-8, I hope you have better luck with yours.

Comment: If you call it through the command line, wrapping the path in `normalizePath` _might_ help, but I don't have a similar enough setup to try it out.

Comment: @alistaire - if I use the command line I have no problem writing the characters correctly. The problem is that I want the button to work :)

Comment: You might try setting the encoding in the RStudio preferences. For more reliable advice, maybe ask in the [RStudio support forums](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us).

Comment: @alistaire I tried that option, sadly it didn't work. I'll try RStudio's support forum (I wanted to make sure it is not a general trivial thing that I am missing). Thanks.